# How to specify conditional types for React components props?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

Say I have an object defining my Typography components color and shade.

```
const theme = {
  primary: [10, 20, 50, 100],
  secondary: [20, 30, 80],
  accent: [10, 20]
}
```

Typography should accept 2 props, `color` and `shade`.

Type definition for color can be: `keyof typeof theme`.

How do I specify the type of `shade` prop such that it only accepts the value within the array of the palette defined in the theme object? For instance, if color is accent, shade cannot be 30. It can only be 10 or 20.

Code snippet:

```
function Typography({
  color,
  shade,
  children,
}: {
  color: keyof typeof theme;
  shade: ???;
  children: React.ReactNode;
}) {
  return <div>{children}</div>;
}

function Main() {
  return (
    <Typography 
      color="primary" 
      shade={}>
        Some text
    </Typography>
  );
}
```

Codesandbox - https://codesandbox.io/s/conditional-prop-types-cwy49q

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two possible approaches:

1. Using [generics](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html)
2. Create a union of all possibilities (not recommended for big amount of values)

Either of the approaches will require a change in `theme`.

Currently, the type of the `theme` is `Record<string, number[]>` which is not suitable for us. We have to prevent the compiler from widening types to their primitives.

This can be done by using [const assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html#const-assertions):

```
const theme = {
  primary: [10, 20, 50, 100],
  secondary: [20, 30, 80],
  accent: [10, 20],
} as const;
```

The problem with const assertion is that we lose type checking and if you use Typescript `>= 4.9` it can be fixed with [satisfies](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-9.html) operator:

```
const theme = {
  primary: [10, 20, 50, 100],
  secondary: [20, 30, 80],
  accent: [10, 20],
} as const satisfies Record<string, readonly number[]>;
```

Since const assertion converts everything to `readonly` it is crucial to write `readonly number[]` in `satisfies` instead of just `number[]`.

Let's create a type for the `theme`:

```
// type Theme = {
//     readonly primary: readonly [10, 20, 50, 100];
//     readonly secondary: readonly [20, 30, 80];
//     readonly accent: readonly [10, 20];
// }
type Theme = typeof theme;
```

Approach with generics:

`Typography` will accept a generic parameter constrained by the `keyof Theme` and by using it we will get the values for `shade` using [indexed access](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/indexed-access-types.html):

```
function Typography<T extends keyof Theme>({
  color,
  shade,
  children,
}: {
  color: T;
  shade: Theme[T][number];
  children: React.ReactNode;
}) {
  return <div>{children}</div>;
}
```

Approach with the union of possible values:

By using [mapped types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html) we will map through `Theme` and generate a union of `{color: string, shade: number}`:

```
  type PossibleValuesUnion = {
    [K in keyof Theme]: { color: K, shade: Theme[K][number] }
  }[keyof Theme]
```

Usage:

```
 function Typography({
    color,
    shade,
    children,
  }: PossibleValuesUnion & {
    children: React.ReactNode;
  }) {
    return <div>{children}</div>;
  }
```

Either of these should do the trick, personally, I would recommend the first approach if the `theme` will grow bigger.

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=5.0.4#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDG8BmUIjgcilQ3wG4BYAKCrQgDsBneGACyRCTgF44BvKuHDBRQKKAE8AXHADaARgAMAGjgAmZXACsGxQoC6SgXAZJadACZips9SoDMGgBz7DlQejRI6MafI3qDKgBfOBQGODMmYxQYYAZMYCRw5FoocwAeJhE6AHMVIhRzegAbcTg6AFcQACMkKBk9AD4KakoAeja4GHEwTgAVNg5uPioOwXGCorpSoREQK2lJkrK-FVstHQV9FrHxuCXpspMzSwlF1CmZmXWHFWc9Hc69g5mPLx99i+XZRTXt0c6QSo3V6cAG7E4PBBSAgmC6gyQLWBPU4AAUIAwGMBqsUkAA1FDFCpJACqdGA9GG-DcsgA0nBgHQ4ABrJDiWFghF6aS8CIQYrQaS0lQMFiFJDScEcGS0vQySo1Op6OBAyhBGSs9lwqVIPRUKiYCp0DAUpl9HoQHJQFBgFjidJ9OBIAAeMC85nCmo5OsaAApqYJaAKoK5BKLxaGIixgMVzEQ6K4gjyjEHBWCWmGxeYJZyITI+nKFbUoA8U9HY-HpMh0DAAHTVjAAOQg2ZaQQAlCMaUQYBUoEz0uZgAA3Rq8NDluNeILpNpD0dt-WUQ3G2KUgCyKEZvs7Ac+vf7cF9RkEDotVptdpP41TUC4ACJhKIJPfr5nxVxeLogo033AAMq4Jwbqutes7mpAF62uIv40u2i6tHQKAcAwYDoJw-6mPQ5gAIJgMIEDoCwXaCNCcDopi2K4gSRKkuSlI8HuggygyTJetqXI8nywZCiKWY5jqMqFlUxbKqqgjquxuYcHqrRGCuJqUhBlrWtB-rXrekbvtmWlRjGU4JkYSbkRiWI4vihLEgwZKmnAABkJE3pOlaIMQdYNjAzatkZu7Xj2fYDvOY4Tvp8YznOI7NEZS6CApa5Mpu26+TSgj+Yex4peMZ6QapV6ZXst4Pk+8wvn+2lIJ+36wXseyAUMIEwH+4HnrlMHXvB0WtEEQA)

Answer (score 2):

You need to use a generic and infer what `shade` could be from that generic:

```
const theme = {
  primary: [10,20,50,100],
  secondary: [20,30,80],
  accent: [10,20]
} as const

type Theme = typeof theme

type Props<Color extends keyof Theme> = {
  color: Color
  shade: Theme[Color][number]
}


const MyFunc = <Color extends keyof Theme>({
  color,
  shade
}: Props<Color>) => {
  // stuff here
}


// fails
MyFunc({color:'secondary',shade:10})

// works!
MyFunc({color:'secondary',shade:20})
```

[Typescript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=24&ssc=37&pln=24&pc=1#code/FDDGHsDsGcBcAJYAsCmBbF8C88Dex54AHAJwEs0BDEgTwC54BtARgAYAaAJg4FYO3WAXXYF40FBEgATavSbd2AZg4AOISMKVQoFJFgMWHboOABfeJWjxJcELBpFMABRLgi0ADwBhcABtwJPAoAB6wulJWANYoNOAAZogOKPGIqBgAfNh4ohD+JAw+eaLQSJRSKAz2jinI6CiMhQGCjJAArmgARigkJqYg-TYIALI0AGKtkKBZ3n4BQaHhUTE1STVpKOkAFPiEuQEaYqXlZgwubp6NJOkAlNiZO-AA9I9isK1xCagkKGYgI+OTbZ7fIAcnEkhktBB7BKZQq3FM12AQA)